# Moving from arrays to objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays. Each individual array (which may contain some other arrays) holds the data for a form element and maybe some extra information. The form input names are the names of database fields. So, now I can pass this array as a single argument to a variety of functions in my program such as showForm(), createTable(), validateForm() etc etc. I can use these same functions for different websites as I organise the arrays similarly between websites.

I want to move to Objects to contain my data and can see several advantages. However, I am worried that I would end up with a lot of objects. Say a form had 20 input elements I would have 20 objects as opposed to one array of 20 arrays. So, I would have to pass 20 arguments instead of just one to all the functions mentioned above.

I think I am missing something about Object Oriented Programming. I want to be able to create a whole set of objects from a class but then process them all together as a group of objects and not deal with them individually.

Any insight into this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you know that you can have an array of objects?

Comment: You currently have an array of arrays, why not an array of objects?  But I wouldn't bother unless there are real advantages for using objects for just data.

Comment: An array of objects didn't occur to me. I think that does make sense...

Comment: FYI I normally use arrays, as ngi alludes to in the answer, unless you are fetching from the DB into an object that contains methods you need etc. there's really not much of a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage of object oriented programming is that objects encapsulate both data (= fields, often called 'properties' in a PHP context) as well as the behavior working on that data (= methods). Typically, classes of objects are defined based on the 'domain concepts' your application is working with (= the actual, real-life things the objects represent, for example a customer, a sales order, a sales item in an e-commerce app).

If you are currently using an array of arrays, and all arrays in the array are the same type of thing, you could switch to an array of objects, as suggested by others above. If you have a function working on an array of objects, you can easily perform some operation on each object in the array using a `foreach`, e.g.:

```
foreach ($object_array as $object) {
  perform_some_operation($object);
}
```

However, the real power of OOP is only released if you would define that operation as a method of that class (e.g., see [this intro on OOP in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)). That would allow you to rewrite the above as:

```
foreach ($object_array as $object) {
  $object->perform_some_operation();
}
```

This again opens the door to further refactoring into a real object oriented application. As others have noted above, however, introducing 'real' OOP into your PHP application may not be worth the effort if your application is relatively small, if you merely want to group a number of values together, etc. PHP however supports a lightweight way of grouping values into an object, as explained below.

**Creating objects dynamically**

If you merely want to group a number of values together, but want to avoid the use of an array for this purpose, you can use PHP's generic `stdClass` class, in combination with PHP's feature that fields can be [defined dynamically](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch07_12.htm). For example:

```
// Defining a group of values as an array:
$my_person_arr = array('John', 'Doe', 21);

// Defining a group of values by adding fields dynamically to a stdClass object:
$my_person_obj = new stdClass();
$my_person_obj->Forename = 'John'; // Creates and sets a field named 'Forename'
$my_person_obj->Surname  = 'Doe';
$my_person_obj->Age      = 21;
```

This allows you to access, for example, the person's surname as `$my_person_obj->Surname` rather than as `$my_person_arr[2]` (or `$my_person_arr['Surname']`, if you would have used an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead of a regular indexed array).

Of course, this is merely a convenient way of grouping values, and does not leverage the real power of OOP.